# What is 'type' in systypes?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In sys.systypes ... what exactly is **'type'**?

What exactly does .... **bigint > int > varchar** ... order mean when I execute

```
select * from sys.systypes order by type desc
```

Comment: It's just a table with all the defined data types (for columns, parameters etc.) in SQL Server. Their order doesn't have any relevance, AFAIK.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use [`sys.systypes`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175109.aspx). Use [`sys.types`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188021.aspx) instead.

Catalog views like `sys.sys%` are for backward compatibility and there is always a newer, better explained catalog view. In this case, `sys.types` no longer exposes the internal physical storage type (the `type`) column, since that is an internal, undocumented, type id.